# django template tags showing on webpage instead of what they reference

Tags: html, django, templatetags

I think I did a pretty decent job of reviewing all available resources before posting this online so apologies if it was already asked and I missed it.

I am trying to learn how to use template tags and am following an online course while building my own website.

When I put the template tag in {{  }}, the only thing that shows up is the actual template tag. In this case, that is: insert_content. See pic of broken template tag on webpage here:
[image: here]

The way I build my template tag: The tag corresponds to a dictionary key in views.py file that has some text as a value. (And that is the text that I want to see on the webpage). I've gone over each file several times and I found a few typos but even after fixing all of them, the template tag is still showing up on webpage (instead of the value it should be returning).

HTML code:

```
<body>
    <h1>DATA DASHBOARD: FINANCIAL INCLUSION IN PAKISTAN</h1>
    <h2>{{ insert_content }}</h2>
```

views.py code (from application folder):

```
def index(request):
    my_dict = {'insert_content': "Hello, I'm from the app for Pak Fin Incl."}
    return render(request,'AppPakFinIncl/index.html',context=my_dict)
```

Since my webpage is not erroring out, I am assuming that there's no issues with the settings or url pages...?? But I can add that code in too if it helps.

Comment: You are presumably accessing the HTML file directly, rather than going through Django.

Comment: Yeah, it definitely appears to be ignoring all my django code. But my goal was to go through django. I set up Project and Application folders in a virtual django environment and am running the runserver command before opening the webpage. What other information would be useful to provide?

Comment: But how are you "opening the webpage"? What address are you going to?

Comment: aha!! I see what you mean now. You are right, I was just opening up the .html file in my browser instead of opening up http://127.0.0.1:8000/. My template tag shows up correctly now - thank you!